# about csv extension,what is the use of it

Tags: csv

i need some information about csv extension, what is the use of csv extention, how to use it, any simple example

Comment: This can't be a real question. You're asking how to use a file extension?

Comment: no i know how to use file extension

Comment: So, what are you asking? You wrote the question, not me.

Comment: Then you meant to ask about the file _format_, not the _extension_. The extension is just the part of the file name that indicates its format.

Answer (score 3):

Here is all you could possibly want to know about [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values).

And if that doesn't satisfy your unquestionable thirst for knowledge, try the references from Wikipedia and [Google](http://www.google.com/).

Answer (score 0):

It's just a way to indicate the type of the file, nothing more, nothing less.
Could call the file XXXX.doodleberry for all the operating system or the application using it could care about it.

Comment: Wrong. Most operating systems determine the type of a file from its extension. Nothing knows how to open `.doodleberry` files.

Comment: @Cody: not quite true. If you want to **run** the particular file and expecting an associated program to be executed (like Excel when you open a .csv file), then file extension does matter. But you can also run Excel beforehand and open a `.doodleberry` file; it should run without problems. In *nix world, a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) will determine what needs to be run when you "execute" a file.

Comment: @darioo: Yes, you can open it from within Excel no matter what it is named. But the associated program will not be launched by the operating system if it doesn't recognize the extension. Given that the answer says "for all the operating system...could care about it", I think my comment still holds true. The point is, it's simply not valid to dismiss file extensions as completely irrelevant.

Comment: IMHO, the file extension is most relevant to the *user*, who can tell at a glance what is inside a folder, even if just a plain file list is provided. **However**, some apps will check for the file extension when attempting to open the file; while it is broken behavior, it *makes* the application care (IIRC, some old versions of Excel will go crazy if you rename the file to .xml, as they will try to parse as XML, regardless of actual structure); some apps won't even open anything that has an incorrect extension. So, although the applications *shouldn't* care, it is not always so.